# If $\cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})+\cos^{-1}(\frac{y}{b})=\theta$, then $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{2xy} {ab}\cos(\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})+\cos^{-1}(\frac{y}{b})=\theta$, prove 
that $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{2xy}{ab}\cos(\theta)=\sin^2(\theta)$

My trial:Let:

$\cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})=\alpha$,  and $\cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})=\beta$

$\sin(\theta)= \sin(\alpha) \cos(\beta)+\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$

$\sin (\theta)=\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}\bigl(\frac{x}{a}\big)+\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\big(\frac{y}{b}\bigr)$

$\sin^2(\theta)=\bigl(1-\frac{y^2}{b^2}\bigr)\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\bigl(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\bigr)\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{2xy}{ab}\sqrt{(1-\frac{y^2}{b^2})((1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})}$

$\sin^2(\theta)=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{2xy}{ab}\sqrt{(1-\frac{y^2}{b^2})((1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})}-\frac{2x^2y^2}{a^2b^2}$

I could not get the final solution, any idea, maybe there is a better algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Using
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(a+b) = \cos(a) \cos(b)- \sin(a) \sin(b).
\end{eqnarray*}
We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{xy}{ab} - \sqrt{ \left( 1- \frac{x^2}{a^2} \right)  \left( 1- \frac{y^2}{b^2} \right) } = \cos( \theta). 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now move the $\frac{xy}{ab}$ to RHS, Square and rearrange.

Comment: Hi, are we getting a general equation of ellipse from this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Using $\cos(A+B)$ formula

$$\cos\theta-\dfrac{xy}{ab}=-\sqrt{\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}\right)(\cdots)}$$

Take square in both sides

Alternatively

Let $\cos^{-1}\dfrac xa=A,\cos A=?$ etc.

$$\cos\theta=\cos(A+B)$$

Rearrange and square both sides

$$(\cos\theta-\cos A\cos B)^2=(-\sin A\sin  B)^2=(1-\cos^2A)(1-\cos^2B)$$

Replace the values of $\cos A,\cos B$ to eliminate foreign elements $A,B$